# Commits made with online editor not available with 'git pull'

Tags: git, github

Commits I made with the online editor are not available locally with a 'git pull'. I get:

```
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

I verified online and the editor-commits do indeed not show up locally.

Because of this I cannot push new local changes:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally.
```

What do I need to do to proceed?

---

Edit:

I did a 'git fetch' and 'git merge'. Ended up resolving all the conflicts that corresponded to the online edits. Then 'git push'. I think maybe it has to do with a branch not being "tracked". Dunno

Comment: Have you configured your `origin` yet?  What happens when you do `git pull origin master`?

Comment: In fact, what does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: and what branch are you on?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen

`$ git pull -v origin master
From https://github.com/myname/blah
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
Already up-to-date.`

Comment: @larsks
It shows origin as my proper repository (myname/blah).

@NickVolynkin
The proper branch shows an asterisk when I do `git branch`.

Comment: Please answer your own question.